# How to stop record video using UWP LibVlc, not closing app?

Tags: c#, uwp, rtsp, libvlc

I using the UWP project (target 1903, min 1809).
Installed nugets: VideoLAN.LibVLC.UWP (3.3.0) LibVLCSharp (3.4.8)

Goal: I trying to record video N minutes duration using RTSP when I use mediaPlayer.Stop() or  mediaPlayer.Dispose(), then getting the error "An unhandled win32 exception occurred in..."
Construction try..catch doesn't catch.

If I use like below, I don't have exception, but not all files recorded. What I mean, for example:

10 files created. But only 8 files recorded, when I closed the app. If the app is open, then not visible what files are being recorded.

```
     mediaPlayer = null;
     mediaPlayer?.Dispose();
     LibVLC = null;
     LibVLC?.Dispose();
```

Full example:

```
    while(true)
    {
        var name = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("HH\\:mm\\:ss").Replace(":", ".")}.ts";
        var storageFileVideo = await storageFolderDate.CreateFileAsync(name);

        var LibVLC = new LibVLC();
        var mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(LibVLC);

        using (var media = new Media(LibVLC, new Uri("RTSP address")))
        {
            media.AddOption($":sout=#file{{dst={storageFileVideo.Path}}}");
            media.AddOption(":sout-keep");
            mediaPlayer.Play(media);
          
          
          // await Task.Delay(5000);
            //mediaPlayer = null;
            //mediaPlayer?.Dispose();
            //LibVLC = null;
            //LibVLC?.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I also tried like below:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => { /*play and stop or dispose*/ });
```

How I can resolve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Bug has been fixed in version VideoLAN.LibVLC.UWP 3.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Stopping playback would stop the recording.

Comment: I understand this, but I wrote the errors that arise above

Comment: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libvlc-nuget/-/issues/9

Comment: I can't share the full code. Do I understand correctly that this is how you need to enable vlc logs? 
media.AddOption("--verbose=1");
media.AddOption("--logfile=C:/temp/vlclog.txt");
media.AddOption("--file-logging");

Comment: new LibVLC("--verbose=2")

Comment: I did, but log file is not created

Comment: If i created file via UWP    var vlcLog = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("logvlc.txt", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName); media.AddOption($"--logfile={vlcLog .Path}"); file is created, but not wrote

Comment: it doesn't create a file, it prints to stdout/stderr

Comment: Tell me, please, how i can get this logs? I don't know how to use stdout/stderr.